# Swift: Instantiate type <T> instance in a generic class

Tags: swift, oop, generics, protocols

I want a generic class ClassA with a type T parameter that conforms to a specific protocol named ItemProtocol. I want to have an array of T inside the class, but the initialization of a T instance doesn't work. How should it be done?

```
protocol ItemProtocol: Codable {
    var itemId: String { get set }
    var parameter2: String { get set }
    var parameter3: String { get set }
}

struct Item: ItemProtocol {
    var itemId: String
    var parameter2: String 
    var parameter3: String
}

protocol AClassProtocol {
    associatedtype ItemProtocol

    func createItem() -> [ItemProtocol]
}

class ClassA<T: ItemProtocol>: AClassProtocol {
    private lazy var items = [T]()
    private func createItem() -> [T] {
        let newItem = T(itemId: "someDummyID", //Compilation error here
                        parameter2: "ABC",
                        parameter3: "BCA") 
        items.append(newItem)
        return items
    }
}
```

The compilation error I am receiving is:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `T` is `ItemProtocol` and `ItemProtocol` does not define any explicit initializers. Your code will compile if you add the following declaration to `ItemProtocol`:

```
init(itemId: String, parameter2: String, parameter3: String)
```

With that addition, the line:

```
let newItem = T(itemId: "someDummyID",
            parameter2: "ABC",
            parameter3: "BCA")
```

will compile as expected.

Without that addition, the only `init` available via `ItemProtocol` is the `init` declared from the `Decodable` protocol that you get via `Codable`. That `init` is declared as `init(from: Decoder)` which is where the error about the missing `from` is being triggered.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much!
I tried something similar before creating this post, but I was adding a default implementation in a protocol extension that caused me other problems.